# Vue remove duplicate values after sort function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs

**View**

```
<div v-for="todo in sortedArray">
  <b-button block pill variant="outline-info" id="fetchButtonGap" v-model:value="todo.items[0].arrivalTime">
     {{fromMilTime(todo.items[0].arrivalTime)}}
  </b-button>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
sortedArray: function() {
      function compare(a, b) {
        var standardTimeA = moment(a.items[0].arrivalTime, "HHmm").format("HH:mm A");
        var standardTimeB = moment(b.items[0].arrivalTime, "HHmm").format("HH:mm A");

        if(standardTimeA = standardTimeB){
          let unique = [...new Set(standardTimeA,standardTimeB)];
        }
        
        if (standardTimeA < standardTimeB)
          return -1;
        if (standardTimeA > standardTimeB)
          return 1;
        return -1;

        }
      return this.allbookings.sort(compare);
    }

fromMilTime: function(todo){
      var militarytime = todo;
      var standardTimeB = moment(militarytime, "HHmm").format("hh:mm A");
      return standardTimeB;
    },
```

Right now if the `items.arrivalTime` consists of multiple time as 11:00 AM , 12:00 PM , 09:00 AM  and 11:00 AM. At first it sorts out the time using `sortedArray()` to 09:00 AM, 11:00 AM , 11:00 AM and 12:00 PM.

Is there a way to remove duplicate values after `sortedArray()` function? It should be 09:00 AM, 11:00 AM and 12:00 PM.

Comment: 1. Consider putting `sortedArray` in computed property. 2. Unless you have an extremely good reason, don't use `var`. 3. Consider using `dayjs` npm. It's much, much smaller and does the same thing. 4. in your `if` block, you're using single `=`. It should be `==` or `===`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of the following to remove duplicates out of a sorted array.

```
items.arrivalTime = items.arrivalTime.filter((item, index) => items.arrivalTime.indexOf(item) === index)
```

or

```
items.arrivalTime = [...new Set(items.arrivalTime)]
```